# Combine DataFrames on non-equal dt indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes / series;

```
DF1
2018-01-20 10:04:19.20  1088.30
2018-01-25 16:20:09.60  1102.40
```

and

```
DF2
2018-01-19 13:00:00    1032.60
2018-01-20 01:00:00    1146.30
2018-01-20 13:00:00    1047.70
2018-01-21 01:00:00     997.52
2018-01-21 13:00:00     981.80
2018-01-24 01:00:00    1061.60
2018-01-25 01:00:00    1048.20
2018-01-25 09:00:00    1046.90
2018-01-25 17:00:00    1113.90
2018-01-26 01:00:00    1245.50
```

How can I create a 3rd DataFrame with DF2's index and only values on the rows given in DF1, like:

```
DF3
2018-01-19 13:00:00    NaN
2018-01-20 01:00:00    1146.30
2018-01-20 13:00:00    NaN
2018-01-21 01:00:00    NaN
2018-01-21 13:00:00    NaN
2018-01-24 01:00:00    NaN
2018-01-25 01:00:00    NaN
2018-01-25 09:00:00    1046.90
2018-01-25 17:00:00    NaN
2018-01-26 01:00:00    NaN
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the merge function with a right join.

So the code would look something like this:

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2, on='column1', how='right')
df_merge.columns = ['column1', 'right_column2']
```

Comment: Would this work given the indices are not the same?

Comment: Can you trim the index column or convert to a datetime.date object, there is a pd.to_datetime() function you can use.